# sklearn LogisticRegression without regularization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Logistic regression class in sklearn comes with L1 and L2 regularization.
How can I turn off regularization to get the "raw" logistic fit such as in glmfit in Matlab?
I think I can set C = large number but I don't think it is wise.

see for more details the documentation
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

Comment: Yes, you can use `l2` penalty and set the `C` parameter large. How beneficial is it not to penalize? If you do this with a completely separable dataset, then the weights will diverge.

Comment: its beneficial if you want the maximum likelihood solution without regularization, for example if you have a lot of data and you don't worry about over fitting.

Comment: Is there a well-tested Python package that does regular logistic regression? I feel like this is what @HananShteingart is looking for.

Comment: I believe the statsmodels API does logistic regression without regularization - see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203740/logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels

Answer (score 9):

Yes, choose as large a number as possible. In regularization, the cost function includes a regularization expression, and keep in mind that the `C` parameter in sklearn regularization is the inverse of the regularization strength.

`C` in this case is 1/lambda, subject to the condition that `C` > 0.

Therefore, when `C` approaches infinity, then lambda approaches 0. When this happens, then the cost function becomes your standard error function, since the regularization expression becomes, for all intents and purposes, 0.

**Update:** In sklearn versions 0.21 and higher, you can disable regularization by passing in `penalty='none'`. Check out the [documentation here.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

Comment: How large does C need to be if I want to use vanilla logistic regression?

Comment: @haneulkim in older versions of sklearn, you could not blanket disable regularization, so we'd set C to some large parameter like `1e9`. But I believe since version 0.21, you can pass in `penalty='none'`.

Answer (score 6):

Go ahead and set C as large as you please. Also, make sure to use l2 since l1 with that implementation can be painfully slow.

Comment: I have tried C=1e42, why does `l1` and `l2` still give different coefficients for each feature? I have about 100 features, though their coefficients from `l1` and `l2` are highly linearly correlated, but still far from being the same. I thought without regulariztion, the two should return exactly the same coefficients. Do you have any idea what causes the difference, please?

Answer (score -2):

I got the same question and tried out the answer in addition to the other answers:

If set C to a large value does not work for you,
also set `penalty='l1'`.

Comment: That does not disable regularization. It uses lasso regularization.