# Python Sklearn Logistic Regression Model Incorrect Fit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For logistic regression I am trying to reproduce the results from Wikipedia [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) page. So, my code looks like below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

x = np.array([0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.5])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

logistic = LogisticRegression()
logistic.fit(x[:, None], y)
```

But how to then obtain the summary of the fitted model, specifically something like this:

```
            Coefficient  Std.Error  z-value  P-value (Wald)
Intercept   −4.0777      1.7610     −2.316    0.0206
Hours        1.5046      0.6287      2.393    0.0167
```

This is what the Wikipedia page has for the fitted model. If I try to use printing of the coefficients and the intercept, I will receive something like:

```
print(logistic.coef_)
print(logistic.intercept_)
```

> [[ 0.61126347]]
>
> [-1.36550178]

Which is obviously different.

The question is, why do my results differ from the ones obtained on Wikipedia page?

Answer (score 4):

The wikipedia example does not include regularization on the model parameters, but sklearn's `LogisticRegression` uses L2 regularization by default. [Set the inverse regularization strength, `C`, to a very high value to use no regularization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427650/sklearn-logisticregression-without-regularization), e.g.,

```
logistic = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=1e4)
logistic.fit(x[:, None],y)

print(logistic.coef_)
print(logistic.intercept_)

# [[ 1.50459727]]
# [-4.07757136]
```

Answer (score 3):

There exists no R type summary report in sklearn.

For classification tasks, there exists a function : [sklearn.metrics.classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) which calculates several types of (predictive) scores.

To have a R style summary report, take a look at the [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) library.